# Not able to install linuxbrew on my ubuntu machine

Tags: git, ubuntu, permissions, homebrew, linuxbrew

When I try to install Linux brew I m getting permission issue.

Below is the error message I m getting.

```
Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> Downloading and installing Linuxbrew...
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/.git/branches/: Permission denied
Failed during: git init -q
```

I tried to set folder permission but it's not working.

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install.sh)"

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> Downloading and installing Linuxbrew...
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/.git/branches/: Permission denied
Failed during: git init -q
```

Comment: "I tried to set folder permission but it's not working." => What exactly have you tried?

Comment: sudo chmod 755 folder path

Comment: Could you share the exact command you used?

Comment: sudo chmod 755 /home/linuxbrew/

Comment: You might want to ask this question on https://askubuntu.com/ as it's not directly related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

First, `sudo chmod 755 /home/linuxbrew/` would apply 755 on `/home/linuxbrew/` only, not on sub-folders.

Second, in addition of `chmod`, check the *`owner`* of `/home/linuxbrew/` and its sub-folders.
See for instance [`Linuxbrew/brew` issue 550](https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew/issues/550):

> It was caused by having an existing `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew` directory that is not owned by you.
>   [PR 22](https://github.com/Linuxbrew/install/pull/22) should fix that.